# Write and read, socket AF_UNIX in C

Tags: c, sockets, system-calls

I'm writing some socket functions in C but I encounter this problem.
I have a struct with three fields:

```
typedef struct {
  char type;           
  unsigned int length; 
  char *buffer;        
} message_t;
```

I need to wrap  in the same string (type,length,buffer) and write it atomically in a socket. After that with the read function I need to read the message and insert the three fields in the same struct. I don't understand how I can convert an int in a fixed length string.

Comment: You want to do some [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). You could use binary data formats (e.g. XDR, etc...) or use textual format (JSON, YAML, XML, etc...)....

Comment: Why do you want to convert the int to a string at all? Just write the struct into your socket. Since you're AF_UNIX you're on the same machine which simplifies things.

Comment: It's a university project, I can't change the specifics.

Comment: @mah: If the machine on the receiving end of the message is a SPARC or PowerPC machine, but the machine on the sending end is an Intel machine, then simply writing the structure onto the socket stream will lead to misintepretation because the sender is a little-endian machine and the receiver is a big-endian machine and the order of the bytes in the `unsigned int` will be different.  Additionally, there are padding bytes in the structure, and the address of the pointer in the structure is meaningless on the receiving machine (regardless of endianness).  You have to copy the data pointed at!

Comment: @mah: Writing a pointer (`char * buffer` in this case) to the socket only makes sense if the date is read by the same process that wrote it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the socket is AF_UNIX which can only be done between sockets on the exact same machine, so there is no hardware mismatch possible.

Comment: @alk the structure was not made public in this post prior to my comment. Yes, passing a pointer to another process is useless but it wasn't clear that was what was being suggested.

Comment: @mah: ah, you're right...byte order is not an issue (and padding is not too critical).  But you still can't write just a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the idea, although I have not test it, I use a very similar one.

Fisrt you need to pack the struct at both sides:

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct {
   char type;
   unsigned int length;
   char *buffer;
} message_t;
```

To send the packets use a function like this:

```
void SendData(char type, unsigned int length, char *data) {
   message_t packet;

   packet.type = type;
   // convert the int to network byte order
   packet.length = htonl(length);

   // Here we have two options to send the packet:
   // 1 with malloc and one send
       packet.buffer = malloc(length);
       memcpy(packet.buffer, data, length);
       length +=sizeof(char);
       length +=sizeof(int);
       // send it in one shut
       send(mySocket, (const char *)&packet, length, 0);
       // release the memory
       free(packet.buffer);

   // 2 without malloc and two sends:
       send(mySocket, (const char *)&packet, sizeof(char)+sizeof(int), 0);
       send(mySocket, data, length, 0);
}
```

to read te data at the other side, use one like this:

```
BOOL RecvData(message_t *packet) {
   // NOTE: 
   // if packet.buffer is not NULL, the caller of this function must 
   // release the memory allocate here
   packet->buffer = NULL;

   // at the receiver, you need 2 reads:
   // 1 to know how many bytes to read
   // 2 to read those bytes.
   if (recv(mySocket, (char *)packet, sizeof(char)+sizeof(int), 0) > 0)
   {
       // convert the int to host byte order
       packet->length = ntohl(packet->length);
       packet->buffer=malloc(packet->length);
       // if we got the memory, go ahead
       if (packet->buffer != null)
       {
           if (recv(mySocket, packet->buffer, packet->length, 0) == packet->length)
               return TRUE;
       }
   }
   return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use memcpy copy your structure into a void memory block which can be interpreted as a string or anything you like send it to your remote process typecast it to you local structure your values should be restored as you would like them to.
e.g

```
message_t my_msg;
char out_buf[MAX_LEN] = {0,};

memcpy(out_buf, my_msg, sizeof(message_t));

send_it_over_socket(out_buf);
```